# Calling modules in python

Tags: python

So Im a beginner to python/programming and came upon this code in a tutorial, which Im having trouble understanding.

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack
```

What I did was , I went to the site-packages folder in my python directory (which holds all modules). There I could find the directory structure to be : -

```
 pythonds/basic/stack.py
```

The file stack.py has a "class Stack" inside it.
So am I correct in interpreting/relating the import command to this directory structure ? 
Also , whenever such a long chaining of modules happen in python, can it always be understood in such a manner.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Why do you want to know? Out of curiosity, or do you want to manually fiddle around in `site-packages`; the latter is highly not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In command line, you can do like this:

```
C:\Python27\Lib>pip intall pythonds
```

Then this module can work.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the time.

It's probably better to not try and compare the directory structure with the module path, unless you have to debug modules or install them manually.

Sometimes, your PYTHONPATH will be extended to include subdirectories in `site-packages`, and then there'll be an extra subdirectory.

Other times, there can be an `__init__.py` file in the `pythonds/basic/` directory (there likely is), that can contain

```
from .stack import Stack
```

in which case the import path could be

```
from pythonds.basic import Stack
```

Comment: Thanks Evert. I checked it in the directory and found exactly what you wrote. But again for curiosity I have a question that why are we having such an __init__ file in basic directory ? I mean when this "from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack" works totally fien, then why do we again need to create an additional __init__ file in basic directory ? Any intuition on that ?

Comment: The `__init__.py` is executed to initialize the _package_ as soon as it is first used (i. e. something is imported from it).

Comment: An `__init__.py` indicates that the current directory can be treated as a Python package. You can have an empty `__init__.py` file, and that will turn the whole directory (or at least all the `.py` files) into a package. Without an `__init__.py` file in the `pythonds/basic/` directory, you would not be able to execute `import pythonds.basic`, since the `basic/` subdirectory would not be seen as a package. But for this, you can better read through the documentation linked by kkuilla above.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is right.

```
import pythonds.basic.stack
```

This will make all the classes in the module accessible by your script. Whereas,

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack
```

will make only the Stack class accessible by your script.